# What should the Client class of this EchoServer class be?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, serversocket

I am trying to write the Client class of this EchoServer so that the server can echo my input. It seems that the EchoServer can only read the client's inputs and print it without echoing it again.

Here's the EchoServer class.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EchoServer implements Runnable {
    Socket socket;

    public EchoServer(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.printf("connection received from %s\n", socket);
        try {
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
            Scanner in = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());

            while (in.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = in.nextLine();
                System.out.printf("%s says: %s\n", socket, line);
                pw.printf("echo: %s\n", line);
                pw.flush();
            }

            pw.close();
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4343);
        System.out.printf("socket open, waiting for connections on %s\n",serverSocket);

        while (true) {
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            EchoServer server = new EchoServer(socket);
            new Thread(server).start();
        }
    }

}
```

This is my EchoClient class, it reads the system input and writes it to the socket.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EchoClient {
    Socket socket;
    private Scanner in;
    private PrintWriter out;

    public EchoClient(String address, int port) {
        try {
            socket = new Socket(address, port);
            System.out.println("Connected!");
            in = new Scanner(System.in);
            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        } catch (UnknownHostException u) {
            System.out.println(u);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        String line = "";
        while (!line.equals("over")) {
            line = in.nextLine();
            out.println(line);
        }
        out.close();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        EchoClient c1 = new EchoClient("127.0.1.1", 4343);
        EchoClient c2 = new EchoClient("127.0.1.1", 4343);

    }
}
```

It seems that the Printwriter of EchoServer is not writing the echo statements. I wonder why?

Comment: Well, it should read whet the server sends back, otherwise the server's echo isn't heard by anyone.

Comment: Again, you need to read what the server sends back, from the socket input stream. Just like, on the server, you read what the client sends by reading from the socket input stream.

Comment: After closing the scanner and printwriter,it seems that the socket in client is closed, so how can I read what the server sends back?

Comment: Well, the server writes the echo immediately after it has received the line from the client. So, symmetrically, the client should read the echo immediately after it has sent its line. Note that there are mistakes in your code: you don't flush the writer at client side, and you try to connect to "127.0.0.1" which is not a correct host name. Use "localhost".

Comment: I see where my mistakes are, I closed the client writer instead of flushing it! Thank you!!